# Showing percentage in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, decimal, decimal-point

I know that percentage in SSRS report is given by 0% (for zero decimal places) or 0.00% (for 2 decimal places) etc..

My specific issue is that I want to show, say *90* as **90%**, and *34.45* as **34.45%**.

Please note the use of decimal places in both cases.
Is there a way to define an optional decimal places for percentage?

Comment: Have you tried using an expression for this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an Expression to set the Format property, something like:

`=Iif ( Me.Value = Floor ( Me.Value ) , "0%" , "0.00%" )`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom format expression. The one you are looking for is `##0.##%`.

This will display:

```
0%      for 0
0.34%   for 0.34
34.45%  for 34.45
```

In SSRS custom format expressions, `#` means "show number if non-zero".

Comment: This expression gives 100.% for 100 [Please note the dot after 100]. The expression by Mike Honey works like a charm.